# why is the bootstrap icon not changing its size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

Here's the code:

```
<div class = "banner-image w-100 vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items- 
center">
<div class = "content text-center">



  <i class="bi-chevron-compact-down bi-7x"></i>

<p1 class = "little text-white">TUKLASIN&nbsp;&nbsp;  ANG&nbsp;&nbsp;   Hello</p1>

</div>
</div>
```

I used cdn for installation in Bootstrap5. I'd appreciate your help, thank you very much.

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage): We recommend using a `width: 1em` (and optionally height: 1em) for easy resizing via `font-size`. Does the `bi-7x` class exist at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap fs- class for changing the size of you icon

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <body>
    <div class="banner-image w-100 vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-
      center">
      <div class="content text-center">
        <i class="bi-chevron-compact-down fs-1"></i>

        <p1 class="little text-white">TUKLASIN&nbsp;&nbsp; ANG&nbsp;&nbsp; Hello</p1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

fs- can be from 1 to 6

read more : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#font-size

Answer (score -1):

I just used `font-size` styling. From [Bootstrap Icons Docs](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#styling) under the section "Icon Font". Example from there:

```
<i class="bi-alarm" style="font-size: 2rem; color: cornflowerblue;"></i>
```